# Asking user input, outputting into a website search bar

Tags: python, input

So basically I'm working on a mini type of Python program. What I wanna do is that I wanna ask the user for input, and take that input and put it into a search bar on a website. Example:

```
drink = input("What drink do you want to look for?\n")
```

and then from there, idk what to do to take that input, and let's say put it into a search bar on like https://www.walmart.com/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] including sample input and _code_ for what you've already tried to solve the problem based on your own research. As it stands, htis question is far too broad to be on topic.

Comment: Buzz words for your search: scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium, geckodriver. :)